# Liquid Templates Not Parsing!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

Im trying to use Liquid Template Language in my Rails Application, i've watched Ryan Bates' video over at rails cast, i pretty much follow the instructions but it just doesnt seem to work!

When I try something like

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("Hi {{name}}")
@template.render('name' => 'toby')
```

I get

```
hi toby
```

but when i try something like

```
category = Category.first
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("Hi {{category.name}}")
@template.render('category' => category)
```

I don't get the desired result, I get only

```
hi ""
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

When the value is not a hash, you need to tell liquid which methods it can read from the passed object.

[This documentation page](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/getting-liquid-to-work-in-rails) show you how to instruct ActiveRecord.
The quickest way is to use the `liquid_methods` macro.

Comment: The reason for this is to prevent things like `parse("Hi {{category.destroy}}")` from messing with your data.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti this link expired, could you update your answer.